# Как найти искомый массив в многомерном массиве?

Tags: javascript, массивы

Есть многомерный массив в javascript:

```
let win_tbl = [
  [0,1,2],
  [3,4,5],
  [6,7,8],
  [0,3,6],
  [1,4,7],
  [2,5,8],
  [0,4,8],
  [2,4,6]
];
```

Как проверить содержит ли этот массив внутри себя массив:

```
let myhodarr = [1,4,7];
```

Проверка:

```
if(win_tbl.indexOf(myhodarr) !== -1)
```

не срабатывает.

Comment: F. Tomas, если вас мой ответ удовлетворил, то поставьте галочку рядом с ответом слева, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3):

```js
let win_tbl = [
  [0,1,2],
  [3,4,5],
  [6,7,8],
  [0,3,6],
  [1,4,7],
  [2,5,8],
  [0,4,8],
  [2,4,6]
];
let myhodarr = [1,4,7];

console.log(JSON.stringify(win_tbl).indexOf(JSON.stringify(myhodarr)) != -1);
```

Comment: интересное решение!) Прям пробуждает чувство восхищения)

Comment: @Дмытрык Мне приятно, что Вам понравилось :).

Answer (score 1):

```js
let win_tbl = [
  [0,1,2],
  [3,4,5],
  [6,7,8],
  [0,3,6],
  [1,4,7],
  [2,5,8],
  [0,4,8],
  [2,4,6]
];

let myhodarr = [1,4,7];

var found = win_tbl.filter(function (e) { 
 return e.length === myhodarr.length && e.every(function (v, i) { 
   return v === myhodarr[i];
 });
})

console.log(found);
```

Answer (score 0):

Объяснение смотрите ниже:

```js
var win_tbl =
[
    [0,1,2],
    [3,4,5],
    [6,7,8],
    [0,3,6],
    [1,4,7],
    [2,5,8],
    [0,4,8],
    [2,4,6]
],
myhodarr = [1,4,7];

console.log(win_tbl.join('_').indexOf(myhodarr.join()) > -1);
console.log(win_tbl.join('_').indexOf('' + myhodarr) > -1);
console.log(win_tbl.join('_').indexOf([6,1,4].join()) > -1);
console.log(win_tbl.join('_').indexOf('' + [6,1,4]) > -1);
```

**Как это работает:**

Вызов `win_tbl.join('_')` нам даёт такую строку:

> `0,1,2_3,4,5_6,7,8_0,3,6_1,4,7_2,5,8_0,4,8_2,4,6`

Вызов `myhodarr.join()` нам даёт такую строку:

> `1,4,7`

Далее с помощью строчной функции **[`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)** мы ищем 2-ую строку в 1-ой. Если она там есть, то значит массив в массиве тоже есть.

> **Совет:** выражение `myhodarr.join()` можно заменить на `'' + myhodarr` и получим тоже самое, но короче.

**Справка:**
[Array.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)